# How to plot scatter graph of time(x-axis) and two other columns on y(axis) with reggression line?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add regression line on scatter plot using ggplot of Time(x-axis) and two other column on y-axis. Scatter plot is correct but Time is in factor form it doesn't form regression line. Please suggest how can I add regression line?

I already added geom_smooth but it doesn't work in my code

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

my_data = read.csv(file.choose(),header = TRUE)

df<- data.frame(my_data$Time,my_data$Entry,my_data$Exit)

# order the level of time
df$my_data.Time <- factor(df$my_data.Time, order=TRUE,levels= df$my_data.Time)

mdf <- melt(df,id.vars = 1,measure.vars=c(2,3))

gp <- ggplot(mdf, aes(x=mdf$my_data.Time, y=mdf$value,fill=mdf$variable,colour=mdf$value)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = mdf$variable),size=2) +
  geom_smooth(formula= y~x) + 
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="white"), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

gp
```

I want scatter plot with regression line but geom_smooth doesn't work.

Comment: Add some lines of CSV data by editing your question

Comment: What if you do `geom_smooth(formula= value~my_data.Time)`? You also need no `df$` within `aes()`.

Comment: Actually I am unable to find out where I am going wrong..when I change factor time into numeric it shows regression line but with TIme it doesn't I think it is problem related to factor variable ...but I dont how can I solve it

Comment: Could you provide the output of `dput(head(mdf))`?